# how to write a proper IF CASE in mysql where condition

Tags: mysql

how can I write the following sql

```
select * from blogimage where blog_id = '1' and orientation = 'h'
```

BUT ... I want to add....

```
IF(and only if) orientation = 'h' is null... then use orientation = 'v'
```

Comment: `orientation = 'h' is null` is a flat-out syntax error. Do you mean somethning like `SELECT IF(orientation IS NULL, 'v', 'h')`?

Comment: no, i want to get where orientation = 'h' ... but in the case where there is no result with orientation 'h'.... I'll take orientation = 'v' instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you only wants to get 1 record that works with preference orientation = 'h'

```
SELECT * FROM blogimage 
WHERE blog_id = '1' AND (orientation = 'h' OR orientation = 'v')
ORDER BY orientation ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: but I want to prioritise the orientation = 'h' over the orientation 'v' ... so the blog_id = 1  has both  h and v images... I only want the h.

Comment: and if the blog_id has NO image 'h' ... then and only then I'll use the 'v'

Comment: I just updated my answer. I think solves what you need in a easy way.

Answer (score 0):

This statement has a valid `Case` statement. However, if you mean you need an `if exists` statement, I think you need to use a stored procedure for those.  Is that what you are trying to create?

With this statement, you will get back one row.  If there is an `h` row, you will get it back.  If not, you will get back a `v` row, unless that doesn't exist either.

```
select * from blogimage where blog_id = '1' and (orientation = 'h' Or orientation = 'v') Order By Case When orientation = 'h' Then 0 Else 1 End Asc Limit 1
```